# Making script content 'safe' for HTTPS display (Bokeh)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, https, bokeh

I was searching for a solution and came across a removed question from [maria saz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5082720/maria-saz). Fortunately, I was able to see it [cached](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Cwo3LBTyviIJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/39005081/making-script-content-safe-for-https-display-bokeh+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk) by google. Since I have the exact same question, I borrowed the original text:

"""
I'm building a website with Bokeh plots, using inline embedding. However, using an https connection to the site blocks the plots from being rendered, as the source is deemed 'unauthenticated'. Is there a way to solve this?

In the 'Security Overview', it says:

> Blocked mixed content Your page requested insecure resources that were blocked.

Where the two blocked requests were:

bokeh-0.12.1.min.css

bokeh-0.12.1.min.js

...
"""

In my case, I can add a bit of further information. The site is being built using django and google app engine, and if I allow the unsafe content, the bokeh plots work as expected.

How can I serve my content so the scripts will load without the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was addressed simply by referring to the CDN address with "https://"

See the [bokeh embed notes](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are proxying a Bokeh server behind a proxy that is terminating SSL, then you need to configure the proxy to pass the originating protocol on to the Bokeh server, and also use the `--use-xheaders` command line option to invoke the Bokeh server:

```
bokeh serve app_script.py --use-xheaders
```

Can't tell you how to forward the protocol since you haven't specified what your setup is, but there is an example for Nginx and SSL in the User's Guide:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#reverse-proxying-with-nginx-and-ssl

Comment: Thanks. I'm not (to my knowledge) proxying. I just have followed some examples from the bokeh site and include in the header reference to the Javascript : <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.0.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: Oh, apologies, I thought this was in the context of a Bokeh server app. If this is just embedding standalone documents, then all you need to do us change the URLs that you just showed right above to have "https://` in front

Comment: If you would care to make a Pull Request to update the docs page at http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html noting that the CDN resources are also available via HTTPS URLS, that would be appreciated.