# Bokeh server with https via nginx, gunicorn, and flask

Tags: nginx, flask, https, bokeh, gunicorn

I'm having trouble getting bokeh server to render a visualization when using https. I have a similar stack where bokeh server works as expected with http. Additionally, I can get an https connection for a static bokeh.html file. However, passing a script tag to my template.html doesn't work with https.

I have nginx as a reverse proxy in front of gunicorn running a flask app. The flask app pulls a session from a running bokeh server at a particular port. The bokeh server process and the gunicorn/flask process are both monitored by supervisor.

I've looked through the existing bokeh documentation at:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#reverse-proxying-with-nginx-and-ssl

I've also looked through some similar questions here on SO:

[How to configure Nginx with gunicorn and bokeh serve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47578746/how-to-configure-nginx-with-gunicorn-and-bokeh-serve)

[Bokeh Serve HTTPS instead of HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862782/bokeh-serve-https-instead-of-http)

[How to enable SSL/HTTPS on bokeh 0.12.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021512/how-to-enable-ssl-https-on-bokeh-0-12-5)

[Making script content 'safe' for HTTPS display (Bokeh)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065089/making-script-content-safe-for-https-display-bokeh)

I have tried combinations of options for relative_urls = True/False in the flask app and --allow-websocket-origin = "myIP"/["*"] when spinning up the bokeh server.

At this point I think I'm just missing something obvious and I hope someone else will see it. I think the key point is that https works up and down the stack when serving up a static bokeh.html file or other content, but fails when trying to embed bokeh server. I suspect I'm missing something about how to have flask pull a session.

Thanks in advance!

Below are what I think are all of the relevant sections of configuration and flask.app files:

Contents of: /etc/nginx/sites-available/flask_settings

```
upstream gunicorn_flask {
    server 127.0.0.1:6000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name ###.###.###.###;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/https_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/https_error.log;
    ssl on;
    location / {
                proxy_pass http://gunicorn_flask;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_buffering off;
#                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#                proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;

               }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ###.###.###.###;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Contents of: /etc/nginx/snippets/self-signed.conf

```
ssl_certificate /path/to/my/file.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/my/file.key;
```

Contents of: /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000";
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
```

Contents of: /etc/supervisor/conf.d/bokeh.conf

```
[program:my_bokeh_viz]
directory=/my/path/to/bokeh/viz
command=/my/path/to/bokeh/bin/bokeh serve --allow-websocket-origin=###.###.###.### --address=127.0.0.1 --port 6001 --use-xheaders /my/path/to/bokeh/viz.py
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/my_bokeh_viz/Bokeh_Flask.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/my_bokeh_viz/Bokeh_Flask.out.log
```

Contents of: /etc/supervisor/conf.d/gunicorn.conf

```
[program:gunicorn_bokeh]
directory=/my/path/to/flask/app
command=/my/path/to/anaconda3/bin/gunicorn my_flask_app:app --bind 127.0.0.1:6000 --pythonpath /my/path/to/flask/app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn_bokeh/Bokeh_Flask.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn_bokeh/Bokeh_Flask.out.log
```

Contents of: /path/to/my/flask/app.py

```
--- Relevant section of flask app.py
@app.route('/web/path/to/bokeh/viz', methods = ['GET'])
@login_required
def show_bokeh_viz():

  host_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:6001/my_bokeh_viz'
  my_session = pull_session(url = host_url)
  client_url = 'http://###.###.###.###/web/path/to/bokeh/viz'
  my_script = server_session(model = None,
                             session_id = my_session.id,
                             url = client_url,
                             relative_urls = False)
  return render_template("embed.html", script = my_script, template = "Flask")

@app.route('/testing', methods = ['GET'])
@login_required
def show_test():
  return render_template("stocks.html")
```

Contents of: /path/to/my/flask/app/templates/embed.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    {{ script|safe }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Page source from rendered result:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>

<script
    src="https://###.###.###.###/web/path/to/my/bokeh/viz/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=a4c3a28c-8bab-4e54-8ba8-8423914078aa&bokeh-app-path=/web/path/to/my/bokeh/viz&bokeh-absolute-url=https://###.###.###.###/web/path/to/my/bokeh/viz&bokeh-session-id=2GYRA1MPiBBX0qzlIB5ZEMyWQkV9AD1Br1KdgtZoew5P"
id="a4c3a28c-8bab-4e54-8ba8-8423914078aa"
    data-bokeh-model-id=""
    data-bokeh-doc-id=""
></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you are not passing the connection from nginx through to the bokeh server?

Comment: Can you elaborate?  The connection is successful when using http and I'm able to interact with the bokeh visualization. However, when I switch nginx over to https the browser just renders a blank page (with the page source I included)

Comment: Are you sure that you are connecting through nginx when using http? As far as I see you never tell nginx to forward anything to the bokeh server, only to the flask server. Or do you somehow proxy the bokeh server through the flask app?

Comment: I'm purposefully not connecting to the bokeh server with nginx. The flask app handles user authentication/access to the bokeh visualization. The full web server pipeline( nginx <--> gunicorn <--> flask <--> bokeh server ) works as intended with http, but fails on https.

Comment: I don't think this is true, the bokeh server needs websockets, but flask can't handle them (per default). Do you do some special websocket handling in flask?

Comment: If you look at the supervisor bokeh.conf file (fourth one down in the post) you'll see that I'm running bokeh server with --allow-websocket-origin and it is fully functional if I connect directly to that port. When I route traffic through nginx the flask app (sixth file down) pulls a bokeh session and embeds it in a simple template (seventh file down in the post). You can see in the flask app that I'm pulling a session from the port that bokeh server in running on. This pipeline DOES work for http, but fails when I change nginx to route everything to https.

Comment: I'm looking at similar issue.  I believe the core issue here is that internally, the flask <=> bokeh connection is non-secure (http).  Embedding http inside of an https connection is forbidden on most browsers.  If you try this and inspect the log in your browser after the bokeh render fails, you'll probably see error warnings of same.  bokeh can now terminate SSL connections, so a possible approach is to set up bokeh on another sub-domain, get certs for it, then connect to it via https after starting the bokeh server with certs.

Comment: If you found a solution to this with local hosting connection, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of bits I think. By creating a bokeh session you actually just create the script that the browser calls to do bokeh things. In browser it will try to call to whatever you give it, and we need it to call to https://example.com/..... and for nginx to send the bokeh traffic to the bokeh server rather than the gunicorn server.

Best solution I found was to prefix all the bokeh server_session/server_document calls with something so that nginx can send them to the bokeh server rather than to flask and then strip out the prefix with nginx. I tried using the bokeh serve --prefix tag but had some problems with loading static assets.

```
@app.route('/web/path/to/bokeh/viz', methods = ['GET'])
@login_required
def show_bokeh_viz():
  my_session = pull_session(url = http://localhost:6001/my_bokeh_viz)

  # use actual url here
  host_url = 'https://example.com/bokeh_stuff/my_bokeh_viz'
  my_script = server_session(model = None,
                             session_id = my_session.id,
                             url = url,
                             relative_urls = False)
  return render_template("embed.html", script = my_script, template = "Flask")
```

relevant nginx bit:

```
# All bokeh plots are prefixed with some unique route, in this case 'bokeh_stuff'
# Here we will collect these, strip off the prefix, and send the result to the bokeh server
# Sends https://example.com/bokeh_stuff/sliders ⇒ http://localhost:6001/sliders
location /bokeh_stuff  {
    rewrite  ^/bokeh_stuff/(.*)  /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6001;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_buffering off;
}

# All traffic other than static and bokeh_stuff goes to the gunicorn server
location / {
    # forward application requests to the gunicorn server
    proxy_pass http://localhost:6000;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Then in bokeh serve you need to add `--allow-websocket-origin=example.com`

To test what's going on have a look at the console and network requests as well as the bokeh server output (supervisor logs) and see what it gives you. You can also head to example.com/bokeh_stuff and should get the index page even if something is still wrong with your route functions.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but routing bokeh directly from nginx will not accomplish what I need.  I'm routing access to the bokeh server through Flask to handle user authentication. The bokeh server is up and running independently of flask and nginx. It's controlled via supervisor and includes the allow-websocket-origin flag. When I route traffic through port 80 (http) with nginx, I definitely get an active connection to the bokeh server.